# Kendo TreeView remote data with icons

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I had a Kendo TreeView that fetch data from the database, basically it look like this [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/remote-data-binding). And I wanted to add icon in front of the text using this [Kendo icons](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/icons-web). Any idea how can I do this? Or it can be done with the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the example in Telerik website that explains the templates.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/templates

Add a template script to your html

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
            #: item.text #
            # if (!item.items) { #
                <a class='k-icon k-i-close-outline' href='\#'></a>
            # } #
        </script>
```

Add to your tree view definition

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
```

And it´s done.

Edit for the conditional coloring

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">

     # if(item.active=='n') { #
            <span style='color:red'> <a class='k-icon k-i-close-outline' ></a> #: item.group != null ? item.group : item.ledger #</span>
     # } else { #
                <span><a class='k-icon k-i-check-outline'></a>  #: item.group != null ? item.group : item.ledger #</span>
     # } # 


  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I got a simple example [here in dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aSiXUhIc). I try to add an icon if `active=='n'` and color is 'red'` else use different icon. But seem the text color not change? Can u help me here.

Comment: what I mean `subTitle2` and `Title 2nd` not in red color